# how would one prove conjugate symmetry for this inner product

Tags: functional-analysis

In $C^1[a,b]$ where $<f, g>$ us defined to be $\int_a^bf^{'}(x)g^{'}(x)dx$

I'm not sure what a conjugate would look like in this scenario.  How would you go about showing conjugate symmetry i.e. $<f, g> = \overline{<f, g>}$?

Comment: Consider using \langle and \rangle to get $\langle f,g\rangle$ instead of < and > which gives $<f,g>$

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ real-valued?  (I assume you're using the complex conjugate.)

Comment: real valued functions

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is not an inner product because
$$\|f\|^2=<f,f>\int_a^b(f^{'}(x))^2 dx=0$$
for any constant function.  By positive-definiteness one should have that $<f,f>=0$ iff $f=0$.

Comment: If the OP changes the title to reference a pairing instead of an inner product, the question still has content, however.

Comment: @Michael Burr Thanks for your remark. Let's wait for OP's comments.